# Не отправляет форму в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, ajax, form, modal

На сайте 2 формы + много форм в модальных окнах на втором экране. 
Формы которые на сайте работают как нужно, а в модальных окнах кнопка отправки вообще никак не реагирует.

Формы используют один обработчик js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("form").bind("submit", function () {
    // Получение ID формы
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    // Добавление решётки к имени ID
    var formNm = $('#' + formID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            $(formNm).html(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
            // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
            $(formNm).html(error);         
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Пример кода в модалке (все id разные):

```
 <form method="POST" id="form_modal5">
    <input type="text" name="t-number"  placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Получить консультацию" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Я подозреваю, что модальные окна создаются после установки обработчика события. На каждую новую форму нужно заново устанавливать обработчик.

Comment: И метод `bind` устарел, используйте `on` вместо него.

Comment: Модалки в коде изначально. Просто меняется класс на active. Обработчик в футере. Поменял обработчик на $(document).on("submit", "form", function () {

});
И всё равно не работает!